# django apache setup troubles

Tags: python, django, apache2, wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my new Django website onto an Apache2 server (running on a raspberry pi).  Apache is running, and able to talk my app, but it isn't working properly; it's giving me a "Template not found error."  It's trying to find the template`/templates/main.html` from my what I'm guessing is my drive root,

I was using the `runserver` command to develop everything and it was working perfectly.  What I think the issue is that apache server is not running the WSGI script from the base of my application.

This is my hierarchy:

- Application is located in: `/var/www/website/`
- Settings/WSGI file located in `/var/www/website/website/`
- Templates are in `/var/www/website/templates` (they are shared between site apps)
- `TEMPLATE_DIRS` has `os.path.abspath('templates')` in it (which worked for development)
- Have `WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/website/website/wsgi.py` in `httpd.conf` file.
- Have `WSGIPythonPath /var/www/website` in `http.conf` file.
- Using provided `wsgi.py` file; isn't changed at all.

And Here is my `site-available/default` file:

```
<VirtualHost website.net:80>                                                          
    <Directory /var/www/website/website>                                  
            <Files wsgi.py>                                
                    Order deny,allow                              
                    Allow from all                       
            </Files>                                                
    </Directory>                                            
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/website_error.log           
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/website_access.log combined                     
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Since i too had this trouble, i would suggest you to check the template file name, spacing are all perfect. Bcoz even a small extra space in the template file name will through an error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a tutorial on how to deploy Django w/ Apache and mod_wsgi.  I figured if I was having troubles figuring it so, others probably are.  It was written about two weeks back.  If there are any corrections anyone wants to make on it, please tell me.

http://16bpp.net/pages/how-to-deploy-a-django-app-with-apache

Comment: The part about setting up relative paths for template dirs helped me out ```TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use os.path.abspath(). It relies on what the value of the current working directory is, which will not work under Apache. Go read:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Application_Working_Directory